# Code composer inline function linker error

Tags: c, signal-processing, inline-functions, code-composer

I am working with *Code Composer Studio* and I need to inline some functions.
So I put them in a header file (or in `.inl` file referred by a header, both ways) and try to build my project.

The problem comes when I increase the optimization level. The project builds successfully under no optimization, (off or none) but the linker fails to link them and returns:

```
error #10234-D: unresolved symbols remain
error #10010: errors encountered during linking;
```

Has anyone encountered similar issues?

Is is because am not utilizing some kind of flag in the compiler options?

Comment: Unfortunately i can not show all this code.Sorry,i know is important!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/249183.aspx .
When **SW_ROOT** was correctly defined, this issue was resolved.

Comment: Is SW_ROOT related with Stelaris?